# VS2010 Link Warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, linker-warning

I am running VS2010 Express for C++ on Windows 7.
Everything was compiling and linking fine until the latest round of updates.
Now I get a series of link warnings of the form:

```
libcpmt.lib(xgetwctype.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'libcpmt.pdb' was not found with 'libcpmt.lib(xgetwctype.obj)'
```

libcpmt.lib & libcpmt.pdb are in in the Visual Studio lib directory, so I can only speculate that there is some type of path problem. Has anybody else had/solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reinstalling VS2010 and then applying the service pack again.
I assume that it is better to install VS2010 after the initial onslaught of newly installed Windows 7 updates.